# Is angle of friction and angle of repose one and the same?

Tags: friction, terminology, history

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\mu_s$$
Are they both same ? If they are same then what is the reason/history behind this redundant nomenclature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle of repose refers to the angle that the slopes of a stable mount of granular material forms under gravity. This angle coincides with the angle of friction **when the granular material is modelled as a continuum** (e.g., see Mohr–Coulomb theory) with resisting properties based on the notion of internal friction between arbitrary layers of material. For example, if one characterises the internal friction coefficient by $\mu$ then one can conclude that its angle of repose will coincide to the one obtained by the formula you posted.

However, note that the friction coefficient of the granular material does not depend only on the properties of the material that makes up the individual grains, but also on their shape. The same material made up of spherical particles will have a macroscopic angle of repose that is smaller than that of a mount of angular particles.

Therefore, one must distinguish between the two concepts since is is possible to measure a friction angle for the material at the grain-surface scale (e.g., friction angle of quartz) and that resulting from gathering many particles of the same material in a certain distribution of shapes and sizes (angle of repose).

Answer (score 2):

The equation:

$μ_{s}$= tan θ

As applied to an object on an inclined plane gives the relationship between the coefficient of static friction and the angle of incline when there is impending motion (sliding) of the object.

Although I am not familiar with the term angle of repose, I read it is

"the steepest angle which a sloping surface formed of a particular loose material is stable"

Based on the above, it appears to me that the angle of friction and angle of repose appear are indeed related. The main difference is the former deals with the coefficient of static friction between an object and a tilted surface, versus the static friction between the particles that make up an object preventing them from sliding on one another.

Hope this helps.